# Sort XML files that i'm reading from disc by the first 13 characters in the filename in an array

Tags: c#, .net

I need seperate the files by filename.
I'm thinking of having a order by type of approach and sort the files with the same 13 first characters together in an array or something.

So i've comed so far that i read all the "Xml" files in the specific folder and put them into an array.

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\Adam_\Desktop\MiP";  

var di = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);

FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.xml");

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(file.FullName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could do something like that `files.OrderBy(x=> x.Name)`
That is not ordering by 13 first characters but if it is not critical requirement this ordering is working. 
or your full requirement version but a bit awkwardly:

```
files.OrderBy(x=> x.Name.Length > 12 ? x.Name.Substring(0, 13) : x.Name)
```

Grouped data

```
var grouped = files.GroupBy(x => x.Name.Length > 12 ? x.Name.Substring(0, 13) : x.Name).ToLookup( x=> x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: Be aware that `FullName` includes the drive and path, seeing as the base path is `"C:\Users\Adam_\Desktop\MiP"` that will not sort much since the first 12 chars are always equal.

Comment: Keeps in mind you name might be less then 13 symbols and x.Name.Substring(0, 13) throws exception

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

This is the code i used to solve the issue:

var fileList = files.GroupBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 13)).ToList();